# How does this enqueue function work?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, queue

I'm having trouble understanding this line:

```
rear->next = temp;
```

in this queue function:

```
 void Queue::enqueue(int data) {

    Node *temp = new Node();    // make a temporary node
    temp->info = data;          // assign passed in data to it
    temp->next = 0;             // make it point to null

    if(front == 0)              // if there is no front node
        front = temp;           // make this a front node

    else                        // else, if there is already a front node
        rear->next = temp;      // make this rear's next pointer???? why?

    rear = temp;                // in any case make this a rear node

}
```

Wouldn't it make more sense to do it like this?

```
    else                    // else, if there is already a front node
        temp->next = rear;  // make temp point to REAR; not other way around

    rear = temp;                // make temp a new rear node
```

Comment: Your proposed solution does not preserve 'rear' as the last element in the queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `rear` points to the last element. What is wanted is to place `temp` after the current `rear`, and then move `rear` to point to the newly placed last element. So, if we were wanting to enqueue `4` to the queue `(1, 2, 3)`, we want:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4
|              |
front          rear
```

Your solution lets `temp` cut in front of the current `rear`, and then moves `rear` to the cut position. It doesn't even cut properly, since the item before the `rear` is still pointing to the original `rear`. The `rear` isn't pointed to the last item anymore, and your queue would thus be in an inconsistent state.

```
1 -> 2 -> 3
|      4 -^
|      |
front  rear
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought the arrows go the other way (from rear to front) so I was confused. Your diagram really helped!

Comment: @OleksiyDobrodum: You're very welcome. The `enqueue` implementation makes more sense in the context of how `dequeue` is implemented.

Comment: The bigger problem is that the meaning of 'rear' is changed. The queue is not inconsistent since he never specified whether it was FIFO or not.

Comment: @Daeden: Yes, I added *"It doesn't even cut properly..."*.

Answer (score 2):

That code makes sense to me

```
if(front == 0)
  front = temp;
```

This means queue is empty. Add your element, and make the front pointer point to your only element. You understand this already.

```
else
   rear->next = temp;
```

else, there already exists elements in the queue. So go to the last element, the rear, and place the new element at the very back. This is now the new rear. The old rear's next pointer now points at your new rear.

```
rear = temp;
```

Make the new rear official!

Answer (score 0):

This simple example of queue will help you understand the working of enqueue

```
#include<iostream>

#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct node{

int info;

struct node *next;

};

class Queue{

private:

node *rear;

node *front;

public:

Queue();

void enqueue();

void dequeue();

void display();

};

Queue::Queue(){

rear = NULL;

front = NULL;

}

void Queue::enqueue(){

int data;

node *temp = new node;

cout<<"Enter the data to enqueue: ";

cin>>data;

temp->info = data;

temp->next = NULL;

if(front == NULL){

    front = temp;

}else{

    rear->next = temp;

}

rear = temp;

}

void Queue::dequeue(){

node *temp = new node;

if(front == NULL){

    cout<<"\nQueue is Emtpty\n";

}else{

    temp = front;

    front = front->next;

    cout<<"The data Dequeued is "<<temp->info;

    delete temp;

}

}

void Queue::display(){

node *p = new node;

p = front;

if(front == NULL){

    cout<<"\nNothing to Display\n";

}else{

    while(p!=NULL){

        cout<<endl<<p->info;

        p = p->next;

    }

}

}

int main(){

Queue queue;

int choice;

while(true){

    cout<<"\n1.Enqueue\n2. Dequeue\n3. Display\n4.Quit";

    cout<<"\nEnter your choice: ";

    cin>>choice;

    switch(choice){

        case 1:

            queue.enqueue();

            break;

        case 2:

            queue.dequeue();

            break;

        case 3:

            queue.display();

            break;

        case 4:

            exit(0);

            break;

        default:

            cout<<"\nInvalid Input. Try again! \n";

            break;

    }

}

return 0;

}
```